# Using Code Igniter Model function inside JQuery Datatables render function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatables to display all the users of my forum in a page from a table called 'users'. I am using Code Igniter for server-side processing. I looked up the Datatables documentation on how to render data and I got it going. However, I have some PHP variables and functions that I want to echo into a JavaScript variable so I can use them within the render function for the target column. However, I am wondering how to echo a model function from a different table with a parameter into the JavaScript variable, or whether that is even a good approach. Below is my set-up. I have only posted the lines that are relevant to this question (unless I am doing it all wrong).

**Model** (Dashboard_model)

```
public function my_followee($followee) {
    $username = $this->session->username;
    return $this->db->get_where('followers', array('user' => $followee, 'follower' => $username))->row_array();
}
```

**JS:**

```
{   
    "targets": [-1],
    "data": null,
    "orderable": false,
    "render": function ( data, type, full ) {
        var myself = "<?php echo $this->session->username; ?>";
        var is_following = "<?php echo $this->dashboard_model->my_followee('+full[1]+');" //full[1] is username column
        if(is_following == false && myself !== full[1]) { 
            return <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>follow/'+full[1]+'"> Follow </a>';                     
        } else if(is_following == true && myself !== full[1]) { 
            return <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>unfollow/'+full[1]+'"> Unfollow </a>'; 
        } else if(myself == full[1]) { 
            return 'This is you';
        }
    }
 }
```

Basically, I want to check if the loggedin user is already following the currently selected user. If no, show follow button, otherwise, show unfollow button.
 When I check the page, all the buttons have follow (except the currently logged in user), whereas some should return true and show unfollow. I suspect I'm violating syntax rules in this line:

```
var is_following = "<?php echo $this->dashboard_model->my_followee('+full[1]+');"
```

I am new to JQuery and Datatables and can't seem to figure out the right way to do this. Please can someone point me to the right direction, or suggest better ways of achieving my aim? I would really appreciate the help.

**EDIT**
I tried this in my controller that handles the ajax call request

```
    public function users_ajax_list()
    {
            $this->load->model('user/users_model', 'users');
            $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
            $list = $this->users->get_users();
            $data = array();
            foreach ($list as $user) {
                if ($this->dashboard_model->my_followee($user->username) == true) {
                    $is_following = true;
                } else {
                    $is_following = false;
                }
                $row = array();         
                $row[] = $user->profile_image;
                $row[] = $user->username;
                $row[] = ucfirst($user->surname);
                $row[] = ucfirst($user->first_name);
                $row[] = ucfirst($user->state);
                $row[] = ucfirst($user->lga);
                $row[] = $user->followers;
                $row[] = $user->following;
                $row[] = $user->total_posts;
                $row[] = $user->gender;
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            $output = array(
                            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                            "recordsTotal" => $this->users->count_all_users(),
                            "recordsFiltered" => $this->users->count_filtered_users(),
                            "data" => $data,
            );
            //output to json format
            echo json_encode($output);
            echo json_encode($is_following);        
   }
```

It produced errors: wrong JSON response. What am I doing wrong? And how is the best way to do it? And how can I access the JSON variable within the render function for the targeted column.

Comment: There are more ways to do this. I woldn't recommend to mix php and javascript tha way you did it. For example, in your controller's function you can check if the logged user follows the displayed user. You can make it true/false and pass it to the view. In your view check the variable and if it's true you show unfollow button. If it's false follow button.
If you want more help please share with us your controller/model/view.

Comment: ok. will do that now

Comment: You need to include the `$is_following` value as part of the`$row[]`

Comment: Markpsmith I tried it this way: $row[] = $this->dashboard_model->my_folowee($user->username);

Comment: As suggested by Markpsmith, I tried it this way: $row[] = $this->dashboard_model->my_folowee($user->username); I updated the model function to return 1 if true, else 0 if false. The result should occupy column array 10. Now, when I use it in Javascript as full[10] for the check, I get Ajax error and my table goes missing. Any help?

Comment: OK, I finally got it. +1 to Markpsmith for the insight. I thought all the data that could be returned using $row[] would have to come from the same table. Thanks all for the help.